# Rails Selenium Hub and Virtual Box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

I have my development environment running in Virtual Box (Ubuntu), and I would like to preform my tests by launching Firefox on my host machine.

My virtual box network is set to **Bridged Adapter**

My host machine starts the selenium server with this command:

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role hub -port 4444`

My virtual machine runs this command:

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role webdriver -port 5558 -hub http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4444/grid/register`

The Hub on my host machine has this message after the virtual machine connects:

`Failed to check status of node: Connect to 172.17.42.1:5558 [/172.17.42.1] failed: Connection timed out: connect`

I read other questions on stackoverflow that says my Hub's network cannot connect to my virtual machine. Since I have Virtual Box using Bridged Adapter, I wonder how can I make this work?

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The error you have right now, is that the Guest is able to talk up to the Host, but is registering the wrong ip address for the callback. By using localhost / 127.0.0.1, you can tell Selenium node and grid instances to rely on local port forwarding.

Configure the Guest VM to use NAT Networking, and add a Port Forwarding for port 5558 (the default is 5555 for nodes), and port 4444, leaving both ip addresses blank or set to 0.0.0.0 You may also want to forward port 80, so that your Host can see the Guest web server. When using NAT, in the Guest machine, the ip address 10.0.2.2 is the ip address to talk to the Host machine. Here are the commands:

**Host Machine, as Hub**

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role hub -port 4444
```

**Guest Machine, as Node**

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role node -host 127.0.0.1 -port 5558 -hub http://10.0.2.2:4444/grid/register
```